# Using an anchor tag to display a modal in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I'm new to Vue.js I'm trying to make an anchor tag in my navbar component(a link), when clicked display a modal component, but i'm not able to.

I only see solutions for buttons which uses the attribute data target, that isnt available as an attribute on the anchor tag.

I'm also not trying to route to the LoginModal.vue component, what am i doing wrong and who do i go about it ?

Navbar.Vue

```
<template>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md py-3">
    <div class="container">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="/"></a>

            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navlinks" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
              <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"><i class="fas fa-bars" style="color: #283990; font-size:28px;"></i></span>
            </button>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navlinks">

              <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">

                <li class="nav-item mx-4">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">About Us</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item mx-4">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">FAQ</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item mx-4">
                    <!-- <router-link class="nav-link login" to='/login'>{{msg}}</router-link> -->
                    <a class="nav-link login" href="/login">Log in</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item mx-3">
                    <a id="jn" class="nav-link btn btn-primary border-0 px-5 py-2 joinbutton" href="/signup">Join</a>
                  </li>
              </ul>

            </div>
        </div>
  </nav>
</template>

    <script>
    export default {
      name: 'Navbar',
      data () { 
      return { 
        msg: 'Log in'
      }
    }
    }
    </script>
```

LoginModal.Vue

```
 <template>
     <body>
            <div id="LoginModal" class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"  aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"> &times;</button>
                                <h4>Sign Up For Our Newsletter!</h4>
                            </div>
                             <div class="modal-body">
                                <p>body text goes here.</p>
                            </div>
                             <div class="modal-footer">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </body>
    </template>
```

Index.Js in my router folder.NB i dont want to route the LoginModal component. whats the best practice.

```
 import Vue from 'vue'
    import Router from 'vue-router'
    import Home from '@/components/Home.vue';
    import LoginModal from '@/components/Login-Signup/LoginModal.vue';

    Vue.use(Router)

    export default new Router({
      routes: [
        //route records

        { //default route
            path: '/',
            name: 'Home',
            component: Home
        },

        {
            path: '/login',
            name: 'LoginModal',
            component: LoginModal
        },

        {
          path: '/signup',
          name: 'Signup',
          component: LoginModal
        }

      ]
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

I saw your code, so you want to show your modal, right??

best solution is using child component, so you don't need define a new route in vue router, just import LoginModal.Vue to Navbar.Vue, then make it on your template and use v-if to show and hide your modal with @click event

here it is:

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md py-3">
        <div class="container">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="/"></a>

            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navlinks" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
              <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"><i class="fas fa-bars" style="color: #283990; font-size:28px;"></i></span>
            </button>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navlinks">

              <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">

                <li class="nav-item mx-4">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">About Us</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item mx-4">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">FAQ</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item mx-4">
                    <!-- <router-link class="nav-link login" to='/login'>{{msg}}</router-link> -->
                    <a class="nav-link login" href="/login" @click="showLogin">Log in</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item mx-3">
                    <a id="jn" class="nav-link btn btn-primary border-0 px-5 py-2 joinbutton" href="/signup">Join</a>
                  </li>
              </ul>

            </div>
        </div>
      </nav>

      <!-- style your modal and hide it with data property -->
      <login-modal v-if="login"/>
    </div>

</template>

<script>
import LoginModal from '@/components/Login-Signup/LoginModal';
export default {
  name: 'Navbar',
  components: { LoginModal },
  data () { 
    return { 
      msg: 'Log in',
      login: false,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    showLogin(e) {
      // disable anchor tag
      e.preventDefault();

      this.login = true;
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Finally, remember it's better if you use router-link instead of a tag in your vue files!

see more references in:
https://router.vuejs.org/api/#router-link

Also if you want to make professional modals with extra features, try vue-modal too.

I hope can help...

Comment: Thanks, Although I tried that and put an octothorpe(#) in the to attribute instead, so it doesn't route, but it still doesn't work. I've tried it with both the router-link and the anchor tag now. Still nothing shows up on click.

Comment: If you use (#) it will become a route, just redirect you and your component will refresh! So did you try e.preventDefault() to ignore it? Also you can inspect your structure to find your modal, because I'm sure if you used v-if for toggle showing your modal, It worked for you...if i can check your styles, I'm sure can help you better than now